# Cypress+TypeScript. Import class

Tags: typescript, automation, automated-tests, cypress

I am using Cypress.io + TypeScript for test automation and trying to do simple stuff. Import class from one file to another, that code do not repeat.

p.s. I have tried few solutions from stack overflow. It does not helped me.

**Files**:
[File System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DViH7.png)

**Code**:

loginPage.ts

```
export class LogIn {
    //Launch app: http://localhost:6400/
    cy.visit('localhost:6400')
    //Press on menu item.
    cy.get('.navbar-burger').click()
    //Press "Client" menu item near "Login As:".
    cy.get('#navbarMenu a').contains("Client").click()
    //TODO
    }
```

and client_NewJob.ts

```
import { LogIn } from '../helpers/loginPage';
import * as ChaiString from 'chai-string';

chai.use(ChaiString);
const lg = new LogIn();
//beforeEach
describe('BeforeEachTestLogIn', () =>{
    beforeEach(() =>{
        lg.LogIn()
    })
})
//Test
describe('New job page', function() {
    it('newJobCreation', function() {
        //TODO
    })
})
```

I try to run client_NewJob.ts script via Cypress and then I am getting error message:

> ./cypress/helpers/loginPage.ts |
> TS1005: ';' expected.
>
> ./cypress/helpers/loginPage.ts
> TS1003: Identifier expected.
>
> ./cypress/helpers/loginPage.ts
> TS1144: '{' or ';' expected

And a lot same error messages...

How can I import class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue I can see, is that stuff in your `LogIn` class should be in a method not in the classes body:

```
export class LogIn {
    logIn() {
        //Launch app: http://localhost:6400/
        cy.visit('localhost:6400')
        //Press on menu item.
        cy.get('.navbar-burger').click()
        //Press "Client" menu item near "Login As:".
        cy.get('#navbarMenu a').contains("Client").click()
        //TODO
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. :)